# Video tag on Chrome: Fixed Frame

Tags: html, video, mp4

i got a problem with a website and the HTML5 tag video on Chrome.
It works perfectly on the other browsers, but in Chrome, the video doesn't start.
It's fixed o the first frame.

This is the source code:

```
<video id="Video1" loop="loop" autobuffer="autobuffer" preload="preload" autoplay="autoplay"> 
    <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf">
        <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    </object>
</video>
```

And here is the link of the website: http://www.vitalegiuseppe.it/
Anyone have some ideas? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773986/html5-video-issue-with-chrome

Comment: If i try to open only the video in a new tab of chrome it works, so it's not a problem of rendering. It seems autoplay doesn't work.

Comment: What happens if you add this? <script>
    document.getElementById('video1').play();
</script>

Comment: Nothing change.. Still works in Firefox but not in Chrome.