# video tag is not working in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have video in .mp4 format. and I want show that in my html page, For that  I use following tag

```
 <video controls="controls" class="video-ctrl">
        <source src="~/Content/Vedio/Care.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
 </video>
```

This is worked in firefox, but not worked in chrome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [html5 video issue with chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773986/html5-video-issue-with-chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need webm file to play video on webpage. 
Example code below:

```
 <video controls="controls" class="video-ctrl">
     <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm " type="video/webm" controls>
 </video>
```

And [Jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/e2t6x1uw/2/)