# HTML5 <video> loads fine but doesn't play the video in chromium

Tags: javascript, html, video, node-webkit

I have the following HTML code, but it is not working, the video does not start...
Yet, when I test this code in my browser Chromium, it works perfectly.
Any idea of the problem?

```
<video width="576" height="324" controls  poster="">
<source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag or the file format of this video.</video>
```

Comment: does the video play when you press play?

Answer (score 1):

My video is playing fine using your code(in chrome) without giving any troubles so, the problem is with the video you are playing but not the code.

> due to Chrome removing support for h264, on some machines(it entirely depends upon the codecs installed on the computer), mp4 videos encoded with it will not work under certain circumstances these issues with video encoding formats in chrome leads the code to not working perfectly.

there are a couple of solutions in stackoverflow you can give a try:

[MP4 not playing on Chrome version 27.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937480/mp4-not-playing-on-chrome-version-27-0)

[html5 video issue with chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773986/html5-video-issue-with-chrome)

cheers!